# Angular custome dirictive css collapse sub menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am following this article https://medium.com/@alok.lko631/submenu-or-dropdown-menu-without-jquery-in-angular-2-4-5-6-using-only-bootstrap-and-custom-fd716db511be
 for collapsing the menu and sub menu. I am able to implement the logic but the problem I am facing is that I have multiple menu and on clicking the other menu(The menu which is already opened is not getting collapsed) and also whenever I am clicking on any value of sub menu the main menu is getting collapse instead of routing ..

Stackblitz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3ud5q

submenu.component.html

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <section class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
            <li checkToggle *ngFor="let data of listsvalue ">
                <a>
                    <span>{{data.value}}</span>
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav submenu" data-widget="tree">
                    <li *ngFor="let test of data.value ">
                        <a>
                            <span>{{test.value}}</span>
                            <span class="pull-right-container">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</aside>
```

submenu.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkToggle]'
})
export class SidebarLeftToggleDirective {
  @Input('checkToggle') partner;

  /**
  * @method constructor
  * @param elementRef [description]
  */
  constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  @HostBinding("class.active") isOpen = false;
  @HostListener("click") toggleOpen($event) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

submenu.component.cs

```
.submenu li {
    padding-left:15px;
}

ul li .submenu {
    display: none;
}

ul li.active .submenu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Here is stackbiltz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3ud5q. I am not sure my approach is correct. I have a requirment where I need a menu and sub menu and the meun should collapse on clicking

Comment: Yes..and also when we clicked in submenu..it should not collapsed..The submenu value has a router link which will route onclick..

Comment: @Vega Any luck?

Comment: Yes..but when we clicked the same menu after showing the submenu..the menu is not collapsing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196744/discussion-between-subham-and-vega).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be mush easier with inline statement and class attibute than Hostbinding in the directive, as it allows to track only one line.

You just need to track a property that will hold the current opened li index, the class "active" would be then assigned only on that condition:

```
<li [class.active]="opened==i" *ngFor="let innerData of partner.value | keyvalue;let i=index" (click)="opened=opened==i?-1:i">
```

This way, any time there is a click, the evaltion of the property will switch between classes and make the "li"s opened or collapsed

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6wyr8z)

Comment: Yeah it is working now in stack blizt..Could you please also help ....If I want to show li my menu and submenu like this "Sub Test": { 

"Example1": "hai", 
"Ex2": "hello" 

}, what changes  I need to do on the exsisting demo